# The default Caskroom location has moved to /usr/local/Caskroom

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

When I try to install a new cask a message appears:

**"The default Caskroom location has moved to /usr/local/Caskroom"**

How to move the old directory without breaking the links to the new location?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Recipe

```bash
# FIRST SOLUTION

# reinstall all casks (can be slow)
brew cask install --force $(brew cask list)

# --------------------------------------

# SECOND SOLUTION

# move cask directory to its new location
mv /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom /usr/local

# relink existing casks to the new location
for f in ~/Applications/*.app; do oldloc="$(readlink "$f")"; [[ -e $oldloc ]] || ln -sf "/usr/local${oldloc#/opt/homebrew-cask}" "$f"; done
```

> See here for more information: https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/21913

Comment: Tried the first solution. After that none of the apps could be found or started. Second solution worked though.

Comment: Tried the second solution, but it tells me "No such file or directory". For some reason, it's located at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom on my system. Should I nevertheless move it to /usr/local? And would probably need to adapt the relink recipe?

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue and i did following which fixed it.

1.

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null`

2.

```
MBP:~$ brew install terraform
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/terraform-0.7.5.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring terraform-0.7.5.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
zsh completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/terraform/0.7.5: 4 files, 123.3M
```

Comment: This is not the same issue. In the question, asked about homebrew cask not homebrew. And, the homebrew cask application path updates for a new update on homebrew cask, not homebrew itself.